# Indicate the need for a clarification

Tags: phrases

I'm listing requirements for a job position within a company and one of the duties of the position in question is drawing attention to unclear customer requests, and the need for their clarification. I'm not sure how I would put this in words, and this is the best I could come up with: (comes after a list of other duties of the position)

> If the request is vague, to indicate that it needs to be clarified.

So it is not that he directly asks for a clarification of the request, he is only supposed to draw attention to that fact, e.g to someone who is supposed to actually seek for a clarification of the request. 
The verb "warn" is a possible alternative to "indicate" for what I want to say, but I'm not sure it would sound good in this sentence.
Hope someone will provide me with a better phrasing for what I want to say here.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: I've taken the tour, and I'm not sure which scopes you're referring to really, and I'm not convinced you are. I've asked this question after trying dictionaries, Google, and all possible sources I have access to, and I have clearly explained in what context I need to use this sentence, the dilemma of the choice of the vocabulary I have, and the precise meaning I'm looking for. Now, if you could please take a moment and explain to me once again which part of it you find outside the scopes, and what I can do to keep your put on hold warnings off the questions I ask in the future.

Comment: Let's start with "questions which lack results of research are out of scope." This does not mean only that you must do research. You must share the results of your research in the question post.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

"Advise employees on insufficient customer request requirements; outlining deficiencies in details as needed."

*modified from the following, based on clarifications:
"Evaluate submitted (or escalated) customer requests for clarity and detail; solicit additional detail as needed from submitting department/employee."*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Gracie! Unfortunately, I didn't put my question clearly obviously. He or she is going to cover a superior position in the company, and that person is supposed to point to the vagueness of customer requests, and order an employee at a lower rank to ask for clarification or otherwise deal with that problem. 
Would my phrasing, in such scenario, be too far off the mark?

Comment: Ah okay - I've changed my original response to reflect the reflect the clarification.  I'm not sure that's an improvement or less wordy, but I felt obligated to try given that I posted an answer. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help again Gracie! That will work, but could I incorporate the meaning of "warning" or "alert" here, and say that his/her duty is to alert the person in charge of handling those requests, who is below him or her in rank, to the vagueness of the request?

Comment: Yes but I agree with you that those words ("warn", "alert") could be inferred as more harsh than you intend.  Maybe you could try "Advise (or mentor?) employees on detail requirements (or insufficient requirements?) regarding customer requests as needed."

Comment: That was exactly my dilemma, the right choice of the verb, and yes i felt that "warn" sounded too harsh in this context. Thank you for another suggestion, I'll go with "advise" then. Just one more idea, if I'm not asking too much, would "point to" work here: To point to vagueness in customer requests.. ?

Comment: Yes, I think "point to," "outline," or "define" could work: "Point to/outline/define deficiencies in customer request details."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42675/discussion-between-gracie-and-rejlan-givens).